# Optimising dataframe filtering based on rule based table with thresholds and operation signs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

A grid table defines filtering rules.The rows of the grid table correspond in ColA from the second table while the columns from the grid table correspond to the ColB of the second table.
Goal: if the the combination of ColA and Col B falls under the interval appeared in the grid table with value 1 then I want to create a new column in the second table with value 1 otherwise zero.
[image]

[image: Below the data]

```
import pandas as pd 
grids= pd.DataFrame(data = {"<0.1": [0,0,0,1], "<0.2": [0,0,1,1], ">=0.2": [0,0,1,0]}, index=["<0.1", "<0.2","<0.3", ">=0.3" ] ) 
df = pd.DataFrame({"ColA": [0.01, 0.15, 0.24, 0.5], "ColB": [0.15, 0.15, 0.24, 0.5]})
```

The output should like '
[image]

Currently, I have made a very large functions with for loops. Any ideas on how to optimise it with pandas or any other trick?

Answer (score 1):

May not be a great solution. But here's my two cents:

```
df['Flag'] = ''
for m in range(len(df)):
  row_idx = [n for n,x in enumerate([eval(i) for i in list(str(df['ColA'][m]) + grids.index)]) if x]
  col_idx = [n for n,x in enumerate([eval(i) for i in list(str(df['ColB'][m]) + grids.columns)]) if x]

  df['Flag'][m] = 1 if (grids.iloc[row_idx, col_idx] == 1).values.any() else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand your intent, but you could try the following:

```
bins = {
    "ColA": [-float("inf"), 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, float("inf")],
    "ColB": [-float("inf"), 0.1, 0.2, float("inf")]
}
idx = {
    c: pd.cut(df[c], bins=b, labels=range(len(b) - 1), right=False)
    for c, b in bins.items() 
}
df["flag"] = grids.values[idx["ColA"], idx["ColB"]]
```

- Use the [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) function to slot values into intervals that are defined by bins corresponding to the filter rules. The `labels` translate the intervals into indices.
- Then use the convienient access to the NumPy array `grids.values` with the result (`idx`).

Result for the following samples

```py
grids= pd.DataFrame(
    {"<0.1": [0, 0, 0, 1], "<0.2": [0, 0, 1, 1], ">=0.2": [0, 0, 1, 0]},
    index=["<0.1", "<0.2","<0.3", ">=0.3"]
) 
df = pd.DataFrame({"ColA": [0.01, 0.15, 0.24, 0.5], "ColB": [0.15, 0.15, 0.24, 0.5]})
```

is

```
   ColA  ColB  flag
0  0.01  0.15     0
1  0.15  0.15     0
2  0.24  0.24     1
3  0.50  0.50     0
```